# JAX-RS REST Services as a library

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

Is it possible to package my rest resource classes in a .jar library so that when they are included in someone's app that app gets the services?

i am currently using jersey (jersey.dev.java.net)

Comment: Would someone else's app be the client or the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I don't see why it won't work GRANTED that person defines the rest servlet in their web.xml to locate your REST package from the jar... like this:-

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Rest Web Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.resourceConfigClass</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <!--  Package that contains all Rest Web Services -->
        <param-value>com.project.your.rest.package.in.jar</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Rest Web Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```